# query en angular2 y firebase

Tags: firebase, angularjs-2.0, ionic2

hola chicos estoy intentando hacer una query en angular2 desde firebase
lo q ocurre es q solo le puedo poner una peticion de consulta si le pido que me arroje los datos de la tabla conde el usuario = al q inicio session funciona, pero si le pido que me muestre donde status sea igual a 1 me arroja el error se sintaxis alguna idea para arreglar esto? gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade el código en vez de imágenes para verlo más claro y poder copy pastear mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo las especificaciones del "query" dentro del import del firebase,
puedes observar que la opción "orderByValue" solo aceptar un boolean:

```
  export interface Query {
   [key: string]: any;
   orderByKey?: boolean | Observable<boolean>;
   orderByPriority?: boolean | Observable<boolean>;
   orderByChild?: string | Observable<string>;
   orderByValue?: boolean | Observable<boolean>;
   equalTo?: any | Observable<any>;
   startAt?: any | Observable<any>;
   endAt?: any | Observable<any>;
   limitToFirst?: number | Observable<number>;
   limitToLast?: number | Observable<number>;
}
```

Por otro lado, las "querys" solo pueden ser ordenadas por un tipo de de método específico. Esto significa que solo podrás ordenar por OrderByKey, orderByPriority, orderByChild o orderByValue.

Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo